# Transversals of Latin Squares

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

[According to this thesis](http://www.math.kun.nl/~bosma/students/gorissen/gorissenmscthesis.pdf), page $28$, the following Latin Square has $3$ $0$-s transversals: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 3\\ 3 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 1\\ 4 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 2\\5 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 4\end{bmatrix} \implies \begin{bmatrix}1 & & & &\\ & & & 5 & \\ & & 4 & & \\ & & & & 2\\ & 3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}& & & 4 &\\2 & & & &\\ & & & & 1 \\ & & 5 & &\\ & 3\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}& & & &5\\& & 1 & &\\ & & & 2 &\\4 & & & &\\& 3\end{bmatrix}.$$ The definition of a $0$-s transversal for a Latin square of order $n$ is

> a set of $n$ ordered triples such that the first and second entries are the rows and columns respectively in which the values $1,\ldots,n$ occur exactly once and the third entry of the triple is the value, of which there are $n$ distinct values.

Basically, we need to visit each row and column only **once** and we must have $5$ distinct symbols at the end. I can represent each transversal as $$t_1 = \{(1,1,1),(2,4,5),(3,3,4),(4,5,2),(5,2,3)\}$$ $$t_2 = \{(1,4,4),(2,1,2),(3,5,1),(4,3,5),(5,2,3)\}$$ $$t_3 = \{(1,5,5),(2,3,1),(3,4,2),(4,1,4),(5,2,3)\}$$ So why are these the *only* three? How do I know there are only three of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any slick way to determine that this Latin square has exactly $3$ transversals---we just count them.  E.g., here's some [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
L:=[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,1,5,3],[3,5,4,2,1],[4,1,5,3,2],[5,3,2,1,4]];;

ExtendPartialTransversal:=function(T)
  local i,j,TNew;

  # we try to add entry (i,j,L[i][j]) to T without clashing  

  # looking at row i
  i:=Size(T)+1;

  # looking at column j
  for j in [1..5] do

    # column already used
    if(ForAny([1..i-1],k->T[k][2]=j)) then continue; fi;

    # symbol already used
    if(ForAny([1..i-1],k->T[k][3]=L[i][j])) then continue; fi;

    # add to partial transversal
    TNew:=Concatenation(T,[[i,j,L[i][j]]]);

    # if transversal complete, then print, otherwise extend
    if(Size(TNew)=5) then
      Print(TNew,"\n");
    else
      ExtendPartialTransversal(TNew);
    fi;

  od;
end;;

# start with the empty partial transversal
ExtendPartialTransversal([]);
```

which returns the three transversals:

```
[ [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 4, 5 ], [ 3, 3, 4 ], [ 4, 5, 2 ], [ 5, 2, 3 ] ]
[ [ 1, 4, 4 ], [ 2, 1, 2 ], [ 3, 5, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 5 ], [ 5, 2, 3 ] ]
[ [ 1, 5, 5 ], [ 2, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 4, 2 ], [ 4, 1, 4 ], [ 5, 2, 3 ] ]
```

and shows there's no others by exhaustive search.

Comment: Is there a simple modification to your code that seeks out only disjoint transversals?  To the best of my understanding, I noticed that the code selects a row, column, then prints the symbol in that position.  It iterates through until something of length $n$ is generated.

Comment: The code only looks at one transversal at a time. To talk about disjoint transversals, we'd need to look at multiple simultaneously. It could be done, but it'd require substantial modification (not just a one-line edit).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I'm working with a larger latin squares (specifically 10x10).  In my situation, we already know the position of some transversals.  I want to see if, of all the completions I have found, one of them could be decomposed into transversals.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm working with a larger latin squares (specifically $10\times10$). In my situation, we already know the position of some transversals. I want to see if, of all the completions I have found, one of them could be decomposed into transversals."

If you find all the transversals of the Latin square, then it is easy to find disjoint transversals.

**Example**

This diagonal Latin square

```
0 2 4 7 8 9 5 6 3 1
5 1 9 6 3 2 4 8 0 7
6 7 2 9 1 0 8 3 5 4
9 4 0 3 5 7 2 1 6 8
7 0 3 8 4 6 9 2 1 5
2 8 6 0 7 5 1 4 9 3
1 5 8 4 2 3 6 9 7 0
4 3 5 1 9 8 0 7 2 6
3 9 1 5 6 4 7 0 8 2
8 6 7 2 0 1 3 5 4 9
```

has $104$ diagonal transversals.

Among them there are $8$ sets of $10$ non-intersecting transversals, which gives $8$ orthogonal diagonal Latin squares for a given diagonal Latin square

```
#1

 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 9 7 4 1 3 0 8 5 2 6
 2 5 8 9 6 7 0 1 4 3
 8 4 3 6 2 9 7 0 5 1
 7 6 9 8 5 4 1 2 3 0
 3 2 6 4 8 1 5 9 0 7
 4 8 7 0 9 2 3 6 1 5
 1 0 5 2 7 3 9 4 6 8
 5 3 1 7 0 6 2 8 9 4
 6 9 0 5 1 8 4 3 7 2

#2
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 9 7 4 1 3 0 8 5 2 6
 2 5 8 9 6 7 0 1 4 3
 8 4 3 6 2 9 7 0 5 1
 7 6 9 8 5 4 1 2 3 0
 3 2 6 5 8 1 4 9 0 7
 5 8 7 0 9 2 3 6 1 4
 1 0 5 2 7 3 9 4 6 8
 4 3 1 7 0 6 2 8 9 5
 6 9 0 4 1 8 5 3 7 2

#3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 9 7 4 8 3 0 1 5 2 6
 2 5 8 9 6 7 0 1 4 3
 1 4 3 6 2 9 7 0 5 8
 7 6 9 1 5 4 8 2 3 0
 3 2 6 4 8 1 5 9 0 7
 4 8 7 0 9 2 3 6 1 5
 8 0 5 2 7 3 9 4 6 1
 5 3 1 7 0 6 2 8 9 4
 6 9 0 5 1 8 4 3 7 2

#4
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 9 7 4 8 3 0 1 5 2 6
 2 5 8 9 6 7 0 1 4 3
 1 4 3 6 2 9 7 0 5 8
 7 6 9 1 5 4 8 2 3 0
 3 2 6 5 8 1 4 9 0 7
 5 8 7 0 9 2 3 6 1 4
 8 0 5 2 7 3 9 4 6 1
 4 3 1 7 0 6 2 8 9 5
 6 9 0 4 1 8 5 3 7 2

#5
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 3 7 4 1 9 6 8 5 2 0
 6 5 8 9 2 3 0 1 4 7
 8 4 9 2 0 7 3 6 5 1
 9 6 7 8 5 4 1 0 3 2
 2 9 0 4 8 1 5 3 7 6
 4 8 3 6 7 0 9 2 1 5
 1 3 5 0 6 2 7 4 9 8
 5 0 1 7 3 9 2 8 6 4
 7 2 6 5 1 8 4 9 0 3

#6
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 3 7 4 1 9 6 8 5 2 0
 6 5 8 9 2 3 0 1 4 7
 8 4 9 2 0 7 3 6 5 1
 9 6 7 8 5 4 1 0 3 2
 2 9 0 5 8 1 4 3 7 6
 5 8 3 6 7 0 9 2 1 4
 1 3 5 0 6 2 7 4 9 8
 4 0 1 7 3 9 2 8 6 5
 7 2 6 4 1 8 5 9 0 3

#7
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 3 7 4 8 9 6 1 5 2 0
 6 5 8 9 2 3 0 1 4 7
 1 4 9 2 0 7 3 6 5 8
 9 6 7 1 5 4 8 0 3 2
 2 9 0 4 8 1 5 3 7 6
 4 8 3 6 7 0 9 2 1 5
 8 3 5 0 6 2 7 4 9 1
 5 0 1 7 3 9 2 8 6 4
 7 2 6 5 1 8 4 9 0 3

#8
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 3 7 4 8 9 6 1 5 2 0
 6 5 8 9 2 3 0 1 4 7
 1 4 9 2 0 7 3 6 5 8
 9 6 7 1 5 4 8 0 3 2
 2 9 0 5 8 1 4 3 7 6
 5 8 3 6 7 0 9 2 1 4
 8 3 5 0 6 2 7 4 9 1
 4 0 1 7 3 9 2 8 6 5
 7 2 6 4 1 8 5 9 0 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A latin square is represented as $t_i=(r,c,s)$ which means that r represents row 
of the latin square, c represents column of the latin square and s is the number
whose location is $row=r\;\;and\;\;column=c$.